# What do you call the roof window in a car?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the roof window in a car? You know, many sedans had something like that. You could then stand up on your car and enjoy the view. I am not sure what it's called anymore. Is there a word for it? I am assuming there's a word since it was all the rage during the 2000s.

Comment: in the aughts for the years 2000 to 2010

Answer (score 6, accepted):

["Sun-roof"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunroof) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Also [moonroof](https://www.cars.com/articles/whats-the-difference-between-a-sunroof-and-a-moonroof-1420666252506/)

Comment: I think at one time there was a distinction, one term meaning one that would open, and one meaning one that was fixed. I'm not sure that manufacturers use the terms consistently. I also see "panoramic roof" for a very large glass area which may or may not open.